# Decrypt a file in dart is taking an eternity to decrypt

Tags: flutter, dart

Give this very simple code that's download a 5mb sample mp3 file:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String newDir = '${dir.path}/myDir';
    await Directory(newDir).create(recursive: true);
    await Dio().download('https://www.marcojr.co.uk/tmp/encrypted.mp3', '${dir.path}/encrypted.mp3');
    final File encodedMp3File = File('${dir.path}/encrypted.mp3');
    final receivedData = await encodedMp3File.readAsBytes();
    final key1 = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8("12345678901234567890123456789012");
    final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key1, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
    debugPrint('Starting decryption... ${DateTime.now()}');
    final decrypted = encrypter.decryptBytes(encrypt.Encrypted(receivedData), iv: iv);
    debugPrint('Finished decryption... ${DateTime.now()}');
```

This is taking more than 10 minutes to decrypt !

```
I/flutter ( 4949): Starting decryption... 2020-04-06 14:16:47.041209
I/flutter ( 4949): Finished decryption... 2020-04-06 14:26:59.547053
```

Now, basically the same code using nodeJS that's does the same thing:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://www.marcojr.co.uk/tmp/encrypted.mp3",
    responseType: "stream"
}).then(async function (response) {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./encrypted.mp3");
    response.data.pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('finish', function (err) {
        console.log('start decryption ' + new Date());
        const encryptedFile = fs.readFileSync('./encrypted.mp3');
        const x_iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', "12345678901234567890123456789012", x_iv);
        const result = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encryptedFile), decipher.final()]);
        fs.writeFileSync('decrypted.mp3',result);
        console.log('finished decrypt... ' + new Date());
      });
});
```

Well,this one takes milliseconds to decrypt.

```
start decryption Mon Apr 06 2020 14:43:05 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
finished decrypt... Mon Apr 06 2020 14:43:05 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Any suggestion ?

**UPDATE: https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/issues/126
Basically, everybody faces such issues. Looks like dart is not good enough to perform a simple and basic decrypt task, according with the community.Absolutely frustrating.**